# disposing of an NSManagedObject that was not saved

Tags: objective-c

I created an (overriding) instance of `NSManagedObject`, using `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:`.

If I never saved the context (and did not increase its retain count), do I still need to delete it using `obj.managedObjectContext deleteObject:obj` ?

If so, and assuming it's retained, do I first delete it and then release it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you use `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:` the object will be within your NSManagedObjectContext regardless of whether you retain the NSManagedObject product of the insert call. Its irrelevant to this question whether you have retained the context.

You can always get an instance of that entry by querying the context in an appropriate manner. It might be the original NSManagedObject instance that insert gave you or it might not. Depends on the workings of your app.

If you want that object out of there again you need to delete it from the context or revert back to the most recent saved state somehow.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand correctly: Regardless of the above explanation, I still need to manage the retain count of that object, as any other normal object to avoid a memory leak. Correct?

Comment: Being a class method insertNewObjectForEntityForName: returns an autoreleased object. If you wish to keep a grip on that object you need to retain either by putting in a container or explicitly retaining. But the object is just a representation of the db entry so once you have inserted its there till you delete or dont save.

Comment: Yeah, I understand the whole bit about the object being returned autoreleased. I was just wondering about the memory management aspect of NSManagedObject in general. I assume once I have an object (either through inserNewObject or through fetch), when I don't need the actual object in memory any more, regardless of whether I need it stored in the db, it needs to be released just as a regular object. Correct again?

Comment: To free any NSObject subclass needs a balancing release for any explicit retain.